# fade line on top and right of div

Tags: html, css

Does anybody know how to do this? I need something like this:

[image: black background, green square]

I can find somebody doing it with

---

.

```
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #333;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,hsla(0,0%,0%,0)), color-stop(50%,hsla(0,0%,0%,.75)), color-stop(100%,hsla(0,0%,0%,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
    background:         linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);

}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/HdwKA/662/

But is there anyway I can do if with `::before` or `::after`?

If I want to add one more fade line on the left? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, by giving the element an absolute position, you can position the :before & :after pseudo element anywhere in respect to its element.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  }
.hr {
    background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
}
.hr:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 1px;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&0+0,1+100 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.hr:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50px;
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&1+0,0+100 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

  
}
```

```html
<div class="hr">
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

Here's an example using span

```css
body {
      background-color: black;
      }
    .hr {
      background-color: green;
      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      left: 150px;
      top: 150px;
    }
    .top {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 50px;
      width: 1px;
      top: -50px;
      left: 50%;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&0+0,1+100 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }
    .bottom {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 50px;
      width: 1px;
      bottom: -50px;
      left: 50%;
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&1+0,0+100;White+to+Transparent */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }
    .right {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: -50px;
      top: 50%;
      height: 1px;
      width: 50px;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&1+0,0+100 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */      
    }
    .left {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: -50px;
      top: 50%;
      height: 1px;
      width: 50px;    
   /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&0+0,1+100 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

```html
    <div class="hr">
      <span class="left"></span>
      <span class="right"></span>
      <span class="top"></span>
      <span class="bottom"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for it. May I know if I want another line on the left. Is it possible? What should I do? Because it had use the before and after for the top line and right line.

Comment: whether you make the line longer so it appears on the left & right or use a span inside the div to make the left/right/top/bottom line

Comment: I see. Thank you for your guides, it really help me a lots. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

that works with a pseudo selector. 
I added you a solution to a fiddle based on a DIV element (but could be any other valid CSS selector):
http://codepen.io/marcbaur/pen/ZOxaxE/

```
div::after {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #333;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,hsla(0,0%,0%,0)), color-stop(50%,hsla(0,0%,0%,.75)), color-stop(100%,hsla(0,0%,0%,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
    background:         linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
```

you just have to make sure that you define **content**, **display** and **width** properties.